# Naming objects incrementally

Tags: object, naming

I was wondering how to name new objects something different each time a method is run

```
public class Horse extends Animal{
int horsenum = 0;

}
public  void reproduce(Horse h){
    horsenum ++;
    Horse newHorse = new Horse(); //Here is where I would like to name the new horse "newHorse1, newHorse2, etc."
```

Comment: Make `horsenum` static and it should work..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Are you sure that would be stable?  Stable!  Geddit?

Comment: @skaffman - Unless the horses were on a track..  Then you might have a race condition..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a property of Horse.Name ofType string and name it what you will...